# Visual Studio Team Services "Access Denied" Message

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I have a project in Visual Studio Team Services, I can connect to this project just fine, but when I try to check in or out, I receive the attached "Access is Denied" Error. If I close the error and immediately try again, it works just fine for about 5 minutes. Then I get the error again.

This started happening after I joined my computer to a windows domain. I used Team Foundation Sidekicks to "Update Workspace Computer Name".

Any ideas how I can solve this very annoying issue?

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by deleting all workspaces and mapping in Solution Explorer and remapped all my projects, then issued a get for the latest. Everything seems to be working fine after that.